# Alimentar uma lista com dados do arquivo txt

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, txt

Ola, bom dia!!
pessoal preciso de ajuda!

tenho a seguinte lista criada no html, ela não esta completa, só p vcs entenderem.

```html
<ul class="lista">           
     <li>Datetime:</li>
     <li>Velocidade:</li> 
     <li>$ Inicial:</li> 
     <li>$ Atual: </li>
     <li>$ Financ: </li>
     <li>% Neil: </li>
```

e tenho no JS isso( peguei em um tutorial, e acho que é disso que eu preciso

```js
var numsList = [];
$.ajax( 'Input.txt', {
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(response){
        //response é o conteudo do Input.txt
        var lines = response.split('\n'); //quebra o arquivo em linhas, 
        for(var i in lines){
            var row = lines[i];
            var nums = row.split(','); //quebra a linha em valores separdos por virgula
            for(var j in nums){
                var num = parseInt(nums[j]); //converte o valor para int
                if( !isNaN(num) ) //basicamente verifica se é um numero
                    numsList.push(num); //adiciona o item no array
            }
        }

        console.log(numsList);
    }
});
```

Tenho também um arquivo txt(Input.txt) com algumas informações separadas por virgula.

O que quero é alimentar a lista com as informações do arquivo txt, mas coloca-los na posição correta

por exemplo

eu Tenho o 1º item da lista **Datatime:**  e dentro dele quero colocar o primeiro item do arquivo txt

mas não sei como chamar o JS  no HTML.

Desde ja Obrigada.

Comment: Seria bem mais simples usar um arquivo no formato **JSON**, aí vc não se preocuparia em ficar retirando vírgulas, quebrando em linhas, etc... Se vc usar Json, da linha `success` para baixo, nada que está ali seria necessário.

Comment: certo! e vc sabe como colocar na lista ?

Comment: O problema Lila que me parece que vc é nova na área né?!  Vc saberia adaptar para o seu código aí? Aqui pelo site não tem como fazer Ajax.